# How to get the name of current function?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)
>   [C# how to get the name of the current method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code)

For example:

```
void foo() {
    Console.Write(__MYNAME__);
}
```

print: `foo`

it's possible do it in C#?

Comment: In .Net 4.5, you can use CallerMemberNameAttribute to get the name of the caller. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx ... You can then wrap the body of your function in an anonymous function as in ([CallerMemberName] string functionName = "")=>{ }.  The problems with using the reflection method as in the accepted answer are that (1) the function may be inlined, and/or (2) the function name may be obfuscated if it is non-public and the code is obfuscated.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

Comment: For people using .Net 4.5, there's [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

You can check the stack trace

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// get call stack
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

// get calling method name
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name);
```

But beware, if the method is inlined you get the parent method name.