# Creating Log file for C# windows Application

Tags: c#

I have written a code block to generate log file so that I can get all the functions being called.

I used the `Microsoft.Practises.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging` dll to get the log file generated can I know how to get that generated.

```
string procName = "reports_plan_and_proj.plan_v_paid_inv_pay_method_sum";
Logger.Write("SQL:GetPlanvsPaidInvestPmtMthdSummary():: " + procName, "SQL");
```

Comment: You've told us what you've already done, but not asked a queston.....

Comment: *can i know how to get that generated*, I don't get what your asking here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130504/how-to-get-the-name-of-current-function

Comment: i have written the above code to get the log generated but it doesn't work and the log file is not getting generated can you please guide me in creating a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a class somehow like this one

```
public class LogControl
{
    private static string _Path = string.Empty;
    private static bool DEBUG = true;

    public static void Write(string msg)
    {
        _Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(_Path, "log.txt")))
            {
                Log(msg, w);
            }
            if (DEBUG)
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Handle
        }
    }

    static private void Log(string msg, TextWriter w)
    {
        try
        {
            w.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            w.Write("[{0} {1}]", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.Write("\t");
            w.WriteLine(" {0}", msg);
            w.WriteLine("-----------------------");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                        //Handle
        }
    }
}
```

You call it using `LogControl.Write("I want to log this")`
And it produce an output like this : `[1:19:34 PM Friday, April 21, 2017] I want to log this
-------------`

Comment: This worked but i need to rewrite this in my entire application

Comment: Why rewrite? I assume that if you didn't logged anything by now, there are only a few occurrences there. Otherwise you can use "Find and Replace" function that is implemented in your favorite IDE?

Comment: How is it going? We don't have any news from you