# Get the name of the current executing function from within the function in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, methods

Is there a way to programatically get the name of which method or property the current code is executing under?

`void Test()
{
MessageBox.Show("This is a message from " + GetNameOfCurrentMethod);
}`

I thought about throwing an exception, catching it and parsing the stack trace but there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched? [C# how to get the name of the current method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code%20Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not currently relevant but for future readers .NET 4.5 introduces a `CallerMemberNameAttribute` which can be applied to optional method parameters to get the caller information (providing it doesn't get removed from Beta to RTM!). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx