# Using object type for information passing between modules

Tags: c#, design-patterns, modularity

We have a modular MVVM application. One of the interfaces looks like below

```
public interface ILogger
{

    void ReportError(ErrorType type);
}
```

The ErrorType type looks like below

```
class ErrorType
{
  string Message;
  string Title;
  object Owner;
}
```

Note the type **object**. The module implementing ILogger interface just calls GetString() from this as it just needs the name of the calling module. It usage of object looks like a problem to me. We are developing a loosely coupled application and we are letting any object to be passed between modules?

The usage of justified as object being more flexible and guaranteed to give a type name as compared to a string which could result in a typo. Also the implemetor of the interface not doing anything other than calling GetString().

I request some advice. The usage of object looks to me like the modules dont know how to identify between themselves. Is it good design to use **object** like this?

I am thinking more in terms of

```
 class ErrorType
 {
      string Message;
      string Title;
      string ModuleName;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `string ModuleName` is all what you need now just use it. It will force you to expose minimal amount information and other modules will not be able to cheat and try to base any decisions on type of `Owner` object.

In real code use properties (preferably read only on IErrorType interface) so it is easy to change implementation i.e. to compute ModuleName based on object passed in.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are using is the name of the object, then I would suggest just using reflection to pass that in when creating the ErrorType rather than storing the entire object. Your developers will have to make sure to not use hard-coded values since that will be allowable if you are worried about typos/maintainability.*

However, if you need the object for any other reason, then you should keep it. Otherwise, it is just overhead that is not needed.

Just my two cents, though.

*[Here is a SO question that shows how to get Current Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code) and here is how to get the current module:

```
this.GetType().Module.Name;
```

Comment: @Jimmy No problem, always glad to help! As always, if this is what you were looking for, a checkmark to accept is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to capture stack information (like module name), you should really look into using Log4Net or NLog - no need to reinvent the wheel.

If all your layers are in .Net, I don't see how using the Object type would cause you any problems - it's the base class for everything else.  The question is what are you going to do (or what will others do) with the information?  It only has .ToString, .Equals, and a couple other methods. Do you have a nonfunctional requirement that is driving your logging design?  If "Owner" isn't needed (yet), just don't include it.

Passing or not passing objects doesn't necessarily impact coupling; rather, it's *how much* one thing knows about the other.  So don't add what you don't need.

Comment: note that we are concerned about interface used between modules. The problem with passing object is that it is not quiet evident what the module need from the other module.

Comment: I didn't see your specification that only the name of the calling module is needed; if that's the case, I would use the ModuleName suggestion

Answer (score 1):

> The module implementing ILogger interface just calls GetString() from this as it just needs the name of the calling module

(minor note:  the right method name is `ToString()`)

Well then, you have an *implicit* interface as to what `ILogger` *requires*. Might as well make it *explicit*, and force modules to implement it:

```
interface INamed {
  string Name { get; }
}
```

And then (note how I renamed `ErrorType` to `Error`; other names like `ErrorMessage` would also be fine):

```
class Error {
  string Title;
  string Message;
  INamed NamedModule;
}
```

But of course, having such a simple interface, just to get a name, might be overkill; you can just use `string` as you're proposing:

```
class Error {
  string Title;
  string Message;
  string ModuleName;
}
```

Either way is better than using `Object.ToString()`, which is too implicit and does not communicate its intent or force your *modules* to override it.

Answer (score 0):

the module name is ok when all we need is the module name but this is not the case, there is a different situation where a url is expected as the identifier, and another where url and module name, so what do we do here?

I'm not sure its a simple as just owner or module name, however I do appreciate the implicit nature of using object.tostring.

One though I had was that actually using interfaces to the owner objects to identify the caller, such as IDocument, which will have URL and Text as possible values then the client to the logging service would check to see if the owner is of the type IDocument and be able to do more with it.

There is definitely a need to add more information about the calling class than just Module Name and sometimes it does not even need that.

Perhaps a class heirachy could help.

```
Class Message
{
   string Title {get; set;}
   string Message {get; set;}
}

Class ModuleMessage: Message
{
   string ModuleName  {get; set;}
}

Class URLMessage: Message
{
   string URL {get; set;}
}

Class DocumentMessage: URLMessage
{
   string Text  {get; set;}
}
```

etc.

Though the danger here is that you get carried away with creating more and more classes and no one is ever sure which class they should be using.

Comment: What information needs between the modules is important, and if it makes sense to have a new data structure or interface it can be done. Just passing an object around will do more harm than good.

Comment: but I could refer you back to the comment you set as the answer, this states that the Module Name should be a readonly property based on the object passed in... thus implying that the object is given to the Error class and exposed via the interface as a string - module name...