# Getting the Value of a Method name itSelf into a string

Tags: c#, syntax, methods

i am trying to output a log of methods and their actions if taken and results into a "MyAppLog_ListView" the columnsHeaders of the lisftview Are

```
Record#______MethodName__________MethodsOutput

1      ______GetCurrentTime______success(21:10)
2      ______DoSplitString_______faild(not in right Format)
3......................................etc'...
```

this helps me debuging my program as it's over 1500 lines of code and atleast for me 
it's getting a little too complex , the question is what is the right way to store methods name in a string

```
public void MyMethod()
{
      do stuff 

       if (comleted) MyAppLog_ListView_AddRecord(string for the methods name, outputSucces)
       else if (faild) MyAppLog_ListView_AddRecord(string for the methods name, outputFail)


}
```

how do i get MyMethod().Name to store in a string ?

- ReEdit :

  As to SidAhmeds Answer :

  ```
   public void MyMethodName()

      {
            do stuff 

           string Mnam = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
             if (comleted) MyAppLog_ListView_AddRecord(Mnam , outputSucces);
             else if (faild) MyAppLog_ListView_AddRecord(Mnam , outputFail);


      }
  ```

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could  use reflection to do it :

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot . i was looking at the link then after 4 minutes i red it all knew what the answer was then you made second post , it was good to read too , but some times when you want to just get ahead of things , this simple answer is Just perfect .

Answer (score 1):

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
var methodName = st.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
```