# Get name of running test in Xunit

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, xunit

Using Xunit, how can I get the name of the currently running test?

```
  public class TestWithCommonSetupAndTearDown : IDisposable
  {
    public TestWithCommonSetupAndTearDown ()
    {
      var nameOfRunningTest = "TODO";
      Console.WriteLine ("Setup for test '{0}.'", nameOfRunningTest);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Blub ()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose ()
    {
      var nameOfRunningTest = "TODO";
      Console.WriteLine ("TearDown for test '{0}.'", nameOfRunningTest);
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**
In particular, I am looking for a replacement for NUnits `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name` property.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `BeforeAfterTestAttribute` to resolve your case. There are some ways to address your issue using Xunit, which would be to make sub-class of TestClassCommand, or FactAttribute and TestCommand, but  I think that `BeforeAfterTestAttribute` is the simplest way. Check out the code below.

```
public class TestWithCommonSetupAndTearDown
{
    [Fact]
    [DisplayTestMethodName]
    public void Blub()
    {
    }

    private class DisplayTestMethodNameAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
    {
        public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
        {
            var nameOfRunningTest = "TODO";
            Console.WriteLine("Setup for test '{0}.'", methodUnderTest.Name);
        }

        public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
        {
            var nameOfRunningTest = "TODO";
            Console.WriteLine("TearDown for test '{0}.'", methodUnderTest.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me.  The attribute can be applied to the class to run for all test methods in the class.

Answer (score 9):

See a similar question in Github where the [answer/workaround](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/416#issuecomment-378512739) is to use some injection and reflection in the constructor.

```
public class Tests
  {
  public Tests(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
    var type = output.GetType();
    var testMember = type.GetField("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var test = (ITest)testMember.GetValue(output);
    }
<...>
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to xUnit ... but this did work for me in VS Testing. might be worth a shot.

Reference:
[How to get the name of the current method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code)

Example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetMethod()
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
    MethodBase currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod();
    Assert.IsTrue(currentMethodName.ToString().Contains("TestGetMethod"));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of this option (using it right now) and looking for another option.

Comment: Not sure it existed at the time of this answer but, if you're using MSTest, you can rely on an instance of TestContext in your test class that will be automatically set my the test runner giving you the running test name and more.