# How to get xUnit Current Test Name?

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, xunit, saucelabs

In nUnit we can get current test name like `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name` that I am passing in Sauce Labs with ChromeOptions to show method name in saucelabs like below

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("username", sauceUserName, true);
options.AddAdditionalCapability("accessKey", sauceAccessKey, true);
options.AddAdditionalCapability("name", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name, true);

_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("https://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
```

but TestContext is not present in xUnit. Please help how I can pass the context or method name?

Comment: Would this approach solve your issue? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484839/get-name-of-running-test-in-xunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484839/get-name-of-running-test-in-xunit)

Comment: I used this approach it giving name but the problem is above code is in constructor to share common setup like 
public MyPageTests()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("username", TestData.config["SauceLabs:Username"], true);
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("accessKey", TestData.config["SauceLabs:AccessKey"], true);
    _driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(TestData.config["SauceLabs:RemoteAddress"]), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
}
Any idea how I can use this approach in my case?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/SimonCropp/XunitContext#current-test

Comment: @Fabian It works. Please put same in answer section so that I can mark it. Also need to add 3 nuget package 

1. XunitContext 
2. xunit.extensibility.core 
3. xunit.extensibility.execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments. Now as an answer:

There seems to be already a solution for this. See [here](http://github.com/SimonCropp/XunitContext#current-test).