# Examples of solutions using C# 5 Caller Information

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, c#-5.0, aop

I am struggling to think of real-world usage of [C# 5's Caller Information feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)

In what scenarios do you need to know who called your method? What other usages does it have other than tracing and possibly debugging?

Is it an implementation of Aspect Oriented Programming?

Comment: One possible scenario just answered by @JonSkeet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230580/passing-a-methods-name-as-a-parameter

Comment: @ArinGhazarian That's already mentioned in question itself

Comment: It's not AOP, it's just that when need something like this, you can use either AOP or caller info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One really nice use for `CallerMemberName` is when working with WPF and databinding.

`private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)`

is a convenient implementation for `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether it's AOP, but to me, it's very useful when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Actually Microsoft does give a nice sample about the difference between 4.0 and 4.5:

4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

4.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx

it's pretty useful, especially when you do a lot databinding, either in WPF or WinForm. it reduces the use of error prone of hardcoding the property name, though you could use reflection to achieve similar behaviour.