# How to obtain method name in the original method when using PostSharp?

Tags: c#, postsharp

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 3.5 and PostSharp 3.1.33. When I execute this code

```
[MyInterceptorAspect]
public void Send(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
}
```

it prints `<Send>z__OriginalMethod`, but I want it to print just `Send`. Is it possible at all? (NB: MyInterceptorAspect extends MethodInterceptionAspect and it works flawlessly, concrete implementation is just not important for this problem)

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code

Comment: @Ron.B.I Tnx, kind of. I had to use `new StackTrace().GetFrame(4).GetMethod().Name` which makes me feel a bit uncomfortable because of the magic number. Frames 1, 2 and 3 refer to some of the PostSharp's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PostSharp changes your methods after they've been compiled, one solution is to resolve it at compile time, rather than runtime.

```
string CurrentMethod([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
{
    return caller;
}

Console.WriteLine(CurrentMethod());
```

Alternatively, you could just search the 'mangled' name using a regex, to find the original name.

```
string GetOriginalName(string mangled)
{
    return new Regex(@"\w+").Match(mangled).Value;
}
```

Comment: Hurk, didn't see that. Let me post a regex that you can use.

Comment: Works like charm, I'm accepting it. Thanks Kendall!