# How to dynamically pass name of calling method as a parameter in the same method?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for something like this:

```
public void MyCallingMethod()
        {
           var myObj = new Obj(Context.Method.Name);
        }
```

Or even better....

Would it be possible to determine from myObj what calling method lead to the creation of the object, but this would have to be reliable, because I will be using it for reporting.

Expected result would be "MyCallingMethod" or "MyCallingMethod()" as a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13496108/1789202 No need to use refleciton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at GetCurrentMethod

```
MethodBase method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
string methodName = method.Name;
string className = method.ReflectedType.Name;

string fullMethodName = className + "." + methodName;
```

But i assume that using that kind of ,,thing'' is not good solution for anything. I think you have misarchitected you app

Comment: Please dont use relfection. There are better ways now http://stackoverflow.com/a/13496108/1789202

Answer (score 1):

You could try the .NET 4.5 `CallerMemberName` attribute:

```
public Obj([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
{ }
```

If you call this method like this:

```
public void MyCallingMethod()
{
    new Obj();
}
```

Then the value of `caller` will be the string `"MyCallingMethod"`.