# Get Current Method Name

Tags: c#, methods

I want to have the name of the current Handler being called.

`MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name` or `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name` work fine in debug mode.

But once I obfuscate (using confuserEx) my project the 2 functions return `"System.Reflection.MethodBase ()"`.

I've noticed I could get the name of my function using the following line :
`((RoutedEventHandler)this.MyMethodName).GetMethodInfo().Name`

It returns `"MyMethodName"` which is the expected result.

But it's not generic at all. I'd like a piece of code working when I don't know the current method's name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# how to get the name of the current method from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code)

Comment: If nothing else helps, are solutions involving a preprocessor for your source code acceptable?

Comment: @Thomas, Yahya: Not convinced this is a duplicate, as none of the linked questions specifically refers to the difficulties introduced to make this robust against code obfuscation.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper removed it.

Comment: If the OP is on 4.5 doesn't the `[CallerMemberName]` solves the obfuscation issue? @O.R.Mapper

Comment: @rene: I don't know. The OP should try (and if it does, they can either answer their own question for future reference, or delete their question because the problem does not exist any more for themselves). Just my opinion, but in both cases, the question how to get the current method name in a way that survives obfuscation has not been asked before (at least not in the linked alleged duplicates), even though the solution happens to be the same as for existing, other questions. An alternative might be adding a comment to answers of the existing questions pointing out ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to try and tell you.

Comment: ... that the respective solutions are obfuscation-safe, but I don't think that's well findable for future visitors; it might seem a bit chatty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use reflection to find the name of the currently executing method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153/can-you-use-reflection-to-find-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx):

*Caller Info values are emitted as literals into the Intermediate Language (IL) at compile time. Unlike the results of the StackTrace property for exceptions, the results aren't affected by obfuscation.*

So from your method you could try to call the following method like:

```
public string GetCaller([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
     return memberName;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's working, I was trying this solution thanks to @O. R. Mapper, thank you both for this solution :)