# How to determine method and iterate over parameters you're in

Tags: c#

My class has a method called `GetAll` which has two parameters: first and last name. I want to create a key based on the namespace + class + method + first + last.

```
$"{namespace}_{class}_{Method}_{first}_{last}"
```

Example key

```
CustomerAPI_CustomerRepository_GetAll_John_Joe
```

I am looking for a generic approach that could be applied to all my methods and generates the key.

I am able to acquire namespace and class name using `this.GetType()` and assembly information but I am unsure how to get method name and the parameters it contains.

Comment: https://code-maze.com/csharp-how-to-find-caller-method/

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on your requirements? What do you mean by "applied to all my methods"? Do all your methods include first and last name parameters? Are you expecting the methods to make some kind of method call where they pass the parameter values in? Are you trying to capture the values from some kind of Expression that invokes the method? What problem are you trying to solve by generating this key?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Sorry that wasn't clear. I am creating a method to create a key from (namespace, class method + underscore separated parameter values). This method should be reusable in any method it is placed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the name of the current method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code)

Comment: My favourite way:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34157214/1563833  `public string GetCaller([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "") { return memberName; }`

Comment: @Master: Do you understand that you'll need to pass the parameter values in when you call the method? In C#, you can't just say `GetKey()` and have it gather parameter values from your method automatically.

Comment: See also: [C# Getting value of params using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867482/1563833) or Jon Skeet's concise [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1867496/1563833) "You can't ".

Comment: @StriplingWarrior but one can generate all possible values for parameters even at compile time... granted for some type (like `string`) is only theoretically possible as it produce infinite (yet countable) set of values :).

Comment: Master, please clarify what you want to achieve with that operation. Looks like some sort of *memoization* effort - likely need runtime interception and only possible at run-time at the time of the call (as @Wyck hinted). Some [edit] of the question with that info would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different approaches you could take, depending on how you want to balance performance and simplicity. Here's one example that's relatively simple but doesn't have great performance:

```
using static Helpers.KeyGetter;

void Main()
{
    new MyNameSpace.MyClass().GetAll("John", "Joe");
}

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void GetAll(string first, string last)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetKey(first, last)); // MyNameSpace_MyClass_GetAll_John_Joe
        }
    }
}

namespace Helpers
{
    public static class KeyGetter
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static string GetKey(params string[] args)
        {
            var callerMethod = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1)!.GetMethod()!;
            var callerType = callerMethod.DeclaringType!;
            var methodName = callerMethod.Name;
            var keyParts = new[] { callerType.Namespace, callerType.Name, methodName }.Concat(args);
            return string.Join("_", keyParts);
        }
    }
}
```

For a better solution, it would be helpful to understand the context of your question. For example, if you're just using this key to emit something like a log message or event when the method is called, you could likely use an IL Weaver like Fody, or the experimental .NET 8 [Interceptors](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/interceptors.md) coupled with source generators, to automatically/invisibly add logging code at compile time, rather than leveraging Reflection.

Comment: Thank you @stripling Warrior, exactly what I was looking for.