# How to output the name of the current unit test running in debug mode in the Visual Studio console

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing

I want to debug the launch of several tests and see the messages in the console from them. However, I can not determine to which test each message belongs. There is an method whith [AssemblyInitialise] attribute, but it is executed only once. There is method with attribute of [TestInitialize], but it is performed only for tests of one class, and I do not know how to get the name of the current test in this handler.

**[Clarification]**

I use MsTest for integration tests. I can switch to Nunit if it is necessary for the solution.

Comment: Welcome to [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)
! At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good Luck!

Comment: If you go to the top menu and look in Test => Windows => Test Explorer, the new window will appear, and show you all tests that run, what their results were, and the details of any failures. Typically, your tests should run in a couple milliseconds, so writing them to the Console in Visual Studio won't help too much.

Comment: @krillgar Thanks. I use integration tests. They are very long.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this answer [How to get the name of the current method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652460/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-method-from-code)

I think it does what you need.
In order to know where your logged output is coming from, simply prepend the output of the GetCurrentMethod listed there. I'll re-post it here for convenience.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public string GetCurrentMethod ()
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace ();
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame (1);

    return sf.GetMethod().Name;
}
```

If what you need is simply to see what made the test fail, note that selecting a failed test in Test Explorer will show you the stack trace of the failure.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I do not want to insert a call GetCurrentMethod() into each method. I need define handler to run each test.