# Is it cheaper to get a specific StackFrame instead of StackTrace.GetFrame?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, benchmarking, callstack

If I'm simply going to do the following to see what called me,

```
var st = new StackTrace();
var callingMethod = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod()
```

would it be cheaper to just get that specific frame?

```
var sf = new StackFrame(1);
var callingMethod = sf.GetMethod()
```

I tested with the code below, but I'm unsure if my methods are sound.

---

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
  var method = new StackFrame(1, false);
}
sw.Stop();
Trace.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
  var method = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1);
}
sw.Stop();
Trace.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

// Results
// StackFrame: 850
// StackTrace: 1334
```

Is my approach (and results) correct?

**Edit**

I'd use the [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) attributes, however, I'm stuck in .NET 3.5 for the time being.

Comment: And of course, the most performant code is to not run it at all ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1348853/945456

Comment: If your intention is to just get the "calling" members name, you are better off letting the compiler do that for with the new [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) attributes, which are new in C# 5 and VB.NET 11.

Comment: Your testing methods seem ok, but I would probably test each statement 1'000'000 times, just to be sure.

Comment: My suspicion is - if you got some stackshots of this process, you might find it spending the dominant fraction of its time in `new` (and GC).

Comment: @vcsjones I forgot to mention the limiting factor: .NET 3.5.

Comment: @JeffBridgman you can still use the calling target attributes as long as you are using the C# 5 compiler, you just need to define them yourself. So if you are targeting .NET Framework 3.5, but are using Visual Studio 2012, you can still do this since it's a compiler features. Here's a blog that walks you through it: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2012/06/13/using-c-5-caller-info-attributes-when-targeting-earlier-versions-of-the-net-framework/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [recommendations](http://blogs.perpetuumsoft.com/dotnet/learn-how-to-create-correct-c-benchmarks/) for the compilation the correct benchmark. You should use prime number of iterations (for suppress JIT [Loop unwinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) optimization), run benchmark in Release mode without debugging, use cache warmup, etc.

I added your example in [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/BenchmarkDotNet), look to [StackFrameProgram.cs](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/BenchmarkDotNet/blob/master/Benchmarks/StackFrameProgram.cs):

```
public class StackFrameProgram
{
    private const int IterationCount = 100001;

    public void Run()
    {
        var competition = new BenchmarkCompetition();
        competition.AddTask("StackFrame", () => StackFrame());
        competition.AddTask("StackTrace", () => StackTrace());
        competition.Run();
    }

    private StackFrame StackFrame()
    {
        StackFrame method = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < IterationCount; i++)
            method = new StackFrame(1, false);
        return method;
    }

    private StackFrame StackTrace()
    {
        StackFrame method = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < IterationCount; i++)
            method = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1);
        return method;
    }
}
```

There is my result (Intel Core i7-3632QM CPU 2.20GHz):

```
x86, .NET 3.5:
StackFrame : 1035ms
StackTrace : 1619ms

x64, .NET 3.5:
StackFrame :  981ms
StackTrace : 1754ms

x86, .NET 4.0:
StackFrame :  735ms
StackTrace : 1150ms

x64, .NET 4.0:
StackFrame : 637ms
StackTrace : 880ms
```

Let's look inside:

```
public StackFrame.ctor(int skipFrames, bool fNeedFileInfo)
{
    this.InitMembers();
    this.BuildStackFrame(skipFrames, fNeedFileInfo);
}

private void StackFrame.BuildStackFrame(int skipFrames, bool fNeedFileInfo)
{
    StackFrameHelper sfh = new StackFrameHelper(fNeedFileInfo, null);
    StackTrace.GetStackFramesInternal(sfh, 0, null);
    int numberOfFrames = sfh.GetNumberOfFrames();
    skipFrames += StackTrace.CalculateFramesToSkip(sfh, numberOfFrames);
    if ((numberOfFrames - skipFrames) > 0)
    {
        this.method = sfh.GetMethodBase(skipFrames);
        this.offset = sfh.GetOffset(skipFrames);
        this.ILOffset = sfh.GetILOffset(skipFrames);
        if (fNeedFileInfo)
        {
            this.strFileName = sfh.GetFilename(skipFrames);
            this.iLineNumber = sfh.GetLineNumber(skipFrames);
            this.iColumnNumber = sfh.GetColumnNumber(skipFrames);
        }
    }
} 

public StackTrace.ctor()
{
    this.m_iNumOfFrames = 0;
    this.m_iMethodsToSkip = 0;
    this.CaptureStackTrace(0, false, null, null);
}

private void StackTrace.CaptureStackTrace(int iSkip, bool fNeedFileInfo, Thread targetThread, Exception e)
{
    this.m_iMethodsToSkip += iSkip;
    StackFrameHelper sfh = new StackFrameHelper(fNeedFileInfo, targetThread);
    GetStackFramesInternal(sfh, 0, e);
    this.m_iNumOfFrames = sfh.GetNumberOfFrames();
    if (this.m_iMethodsToSkip > this.m_iNumOfFrames)
    {
        this.m_iMethodsToSkip = this.m_iNumOfFrames;
    }
    if (this.m_iNumOfFrames != 0)
    {
        this.frames = new StackFrame[this.m_iNumOfFrames];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.m_iNumOfFrames; i++)
        {
            bool flag = true;
            bool flag2 = true;
            StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(flag, flag2);
            frame.SetMethodBase(sfh.GetMethodBase(i));
            frame.SetOffset(sfh.GetOffset(i));
            frame.SetILOffset(sfh.GetILOffset(i));
            frame.SetIsLastFrameFromForeignExceptionStackTrace(sfh.IsLastFrameFromForeignExceptionStackTrace(i));
            if (fNeedFileInfo)
            {
                frame.SetFileName(sfh.GetFilename(i));
                frame.SetLineNumber(sfh.GetLineNumber(i));
                frame.SetColumnNumber(sfh.GetColumnNumber(i));
            }
            this.frames[i] = frame;
        }
        if (e == null)
        {
            this.m_iMethodsToSkip += CalculateFramesToSkip(sfh, this.m_iNumOfFrames);
        }
        this.m_iNumOfFrames -= this.m_iMethodsToSkip;
        if (this.m_iNumOfFrames < 0)
        {
            this.m_iNumOfFrames = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.frames = null;
    }
}

public virtual StackFrame StackTrace.GetFrame(int index)
{
    if (((this.frames != null) && (index < this.m_iNumOfFrames)) && (index >= 0))
    {
        return this.frames[index + this.m_iMethodsToSkip];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @JeffBridgman, It is sufficient that the number of iterations had no little dividers. I checked the asm code in my example, the loop unwinding optimization does not occur.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for the thorough explanation.